# back button and menu navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, I'm trying to design a mobile version of my site and am stuck on my menu.

Basically at the moment I've got a simple onClick running on the page so if the user decides they don't want to view click whats on the menu then they can click the page and the menu disappears.

But what I really want is a way of using the back button on the browser to return from the menu. I'm guessing it takes some kind of event or setting something, but am at a loss.

I'm a newbie, so be gentle, I'm hoping the community can help me a little as to where to start.

My main question is how to use the back button on a browser within my HTML or JavaScript, any ideas as to how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could change the page's hash/fragment when opening the menu. That's a history event for the browser, without chaning the page. You can detect BACK then using `onhashchange`, which changes nothing on the page itself.

Comment: Or you could you history.pushState(...) when opening the menu.

Comment: i went head and wrote a mini library for it all js based. No history api or css `:target`. What OP wanted can now be easily done by `var h = new hashNav(); h.add('menu');`  http://jsfiddle.net/0uk0g0qq/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0uk0g0qq/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated JS only version:** http://jsfiddle.net/0uk0g0qq/4/ (works everywhere)
*`:target` implementation is buggy in ie. so previous one wasn't working. hash changes only affects css when user directly does something on page, click button that changes hash and unfortunately back button is not considered part of the page*

The all the javascript you need is this:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e) {
    if (location.hash != "#menu") {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    } else if (location.hash == "#menu") {
        menu.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

**Css Only Version:::**

You can do it using just css only. It's time you learned about `:target` selector.

It lets you apply style to whatever is url hash fragment and is the id of element on page.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/0uk0g0qq/1

So i hide menu by default, but if it matches i show the menu. Since hastags in url affect browser history it accomplishes what you asked for.

It was pretty awesome first time i learned it.

```
#menu:target {
    display: block;
}
```

the whole code:

```
body {
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
.cont {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    margin: auto;

}

#menu > ul {
    width: 200px;

    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#menu > ul li {
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

#menu:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i too am just now reading this.  not sure if the poster will use this, but thank you sir, this helps a great deal.  Does this work on mobile?

Comment: It works great, It just doesn't work for IE11, which tends to be what I use. I'll have to check for mobile versions. But it should be ok, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but there must be a better way. It all works for most browsers, but not for my windows phone or on ie11. I'm guessing I need some serious skills to get what I'm after. It might have to do.

Comment: I just checked and yes it's not working in ie11, let me see why.